# How to import lambdaj in the Eclipse projects?

Tags: java-8, lambdaj

I would like to use lamdaj in a Eclipse project and needs to make this import,

```
  import static ch.lamdaj.Lambda.*;
```

I downloaded and added the lambdaj-2.4-with-dependencies.jar inside a ***jar*** folder in the Eclipse as following,

[image]

and then, added the JAR in the Java build path as following,
[image]

What else I will need to do to make the work ?

Comment: Well are you having an error? What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project set-up is correct. The compile error is caused by spelling error in the import statement.

Please change the import statement to
`import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.*;`